# Doubt about claim about complexity of edge coloring powers of the line graph

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, coloring

Likely I am misunderstanding/missing something, but a claim in a paper
appears wrong to me.

According to [Coloring Graph Powers: Graph Product Bounds and Hardness of
Approximation p. 2](http://people.idsia.ch/~laekhanukit/paper/powergraph.pdf)

> Unless $NP=ZPP$, there is no polynomial-time algorithm to
>   approximate $\chi'(L^k(G))$ to within a factor of $n^{1/3-\epsilon}$
>   for $k \in \{2,3\}$ and $n^{1/2-\epsilon}$ for $k \ge 4$.

$\chi'$ is the chromatic index and $L^k(G)$ is the $k$-th power of
the line graph.

Let $\Delta$ be the maximum degree of $\chi'(L^k(G))$.
It is easy to compute. The chromatic index is either $\Delta$ or
$\Delta+1$. Choosing the latter for the approximation gives
absolute error of at most $1$, which is the best absolute error
for integers (not counting equality).

This appears to contradict hardness of approximation, since it
is the best possible approximation, not counting exact result.

> Q1 What is wrong with this seeming contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are correct.  The chromatic index is easy to "approximate".

I believe that the authors meant $\chi(L^k(G))$ instead of $\chi'({L}^k(G))$.
Notice that in the Theorem 1 on p2, it is mentioned that the result you state implies the hardness of the strong edge coloring.

On p5, it is told that the strong chromatic index $\chi'_S(G)$ is equal to $\chi(L^2(G))$.  Thus the case $k = 2$ is probably what the authors were talking about in Theorem 1, which makes more sense with $\chi(L^k(G))$ instead of $\chi'({L}^k(G))$.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed they define strong edge coloring in a very weird way, which becomes the usual one after dropping the prime.

Comment: The square of line graph need not be line graph, which doesn't make sense in edge coloring. Should the correct statement be $\chi(L(G^k))$?

Comment: I believe $\chi(L^k(G))$ is fine.  Working with $L^2(G)$ makes sense for the strong edge coloring - it doesn't have to be a line graph.  Intuitively, say you have edges $ab, bc, cd$.  Then $ab$ and $cd$ cannot be in the same class of a strong edge coloring because of $bc$.  But in $L(G)$, $ab$ and $cd$ are not adjacent, so a vertex coloring could put them in the same class.  In $L^2(G)$, $ab$ and $cd$ now share an edge, preventing them from being in the same class.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't need be line graph indeed. Thanks.